# Spring to Ping: how to configure Spring Rest Service to use External Authorization Server PingFederate

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, pingfederate

Does anyone know how to configure a Spring Rest Service to use PingFederate as an External Authorization Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked this question before, it was closed for god knows why.  But here is the answer that I found.  I based this on a demo that uses Google as an external authorization server.  The problem with the usual demos is that they all use the Spring Authorization Server.  Here is the place to start https://arnoldgalovics.com/google-oauth-with-spring-security-as-separated-resource-server/  Then modify the GoogleAccessTokenValidator like this (below).  Questions, fire away...

```
private HttpHeaders createHeaders(final String username, final String password){
       return new HttpHeaders() {{
             String auth = username + ":" + password;
             byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64( 
                auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")) );
             String authHeader = "Basic " + new String( encodedAuth );
             set( "Authorization", authHeader );
          }};
    }

    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Map<String, ?> getPingResponse(String accessToken) {
        
        //Ping speaks text/html
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
        for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : converters) {
            if (converter instanceof StringHttpMessageConverter) {
                StringHttpMessageConverter stringConverter = (StringHttpMessageConverter) converter;                
                stringConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(ImmutableList.of(new MediaType("text", "html", StringHttpMessageConverter.DEFAULT_CHARSET)));
            }
        }       
        
        //URL
        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(checkTokenUrl)
                .queryParam("grant_type", "urn:pingidentity.com:oauth2:grant_type:validate_bearer")
                .queryParam("token", accessToken);      
        String url =  builder.build().encode().toUri().toString();
        
        //Basic Auth (from Ping, OAuth Settings, Manage Clients
        HttpEntity<Object> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(createHeaders("my-trusted-client", "secret"));
        
        //unused Spring exchange variables
        Map<String, String> variables = ImmutableMap.of("ping does not", "use this"); //token only in queryParam above
        
        //validation call to Ping
        Map map = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Map.class, variables).getBody();        
        return (Map<String, Object>) map;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this using `jose4j` library

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bitbucket.b_c</groupId>
            <artifactId>jose4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

Now, following is the code which validates the JWT and get claims.

```java
        String jwtToken = "<token>"
        HttpsJwks httpsJkws = new HttpsJwks("<Ping Server Public cert URL>");
        HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver httpsJwksKeyResolver = new HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver(httpsJkws);
        JwtConsumer jwtConsumer = new JwtConsumerBuilder()
                .setRequireExpirationTime()
                .setAllowedClockSkewInSeconds(30)
                .setRequireSubject()
                .setExpectedIssuer("<Issuer URL>")
                .setExpectedAudience("<audience>")
                .setVerificationKeyResolver(httpsJwksKeyResolver)
                .setJwsAlgorithmConstraints(
                        AlgorithmConstraints.ConstraintType.PERMIT, AlgorithmIdentifiers.RSA_USING_SHA256)
                .build();
       
        try
        {
           
            JwtClaims jwtClaims = jwtConsumer.processToClaims(jwtToken);
          
        } catch (InvalidJwtException e) {
           
            System.out.println("Invalid JWT! " + e);
           
            if (e.hasExpired())
            {
                System.out.println("JWT expired at " + e.getJwtContext().getJwtClaims().getExpirationTime());
            }
           
            if (e.hasErrorCode(ErrorCodes.AUDIENCE_INVALID))
            {
                System.out.println("JWT had wrong audience: " + e.getJwtContext().getJwtClaims().getAudience());
            }
        }
```

We can integrate above code via SpringBoot interceptor by extracting the JWT token received in HTTP header.